# Using jQuery - By clicking a button change the text of a div

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs, codepen

I am working on a project in CodePen editor. My problem is: How to change the text of a  element each time a hit the button ?

I have an array from which I am displaying random text on a div.
Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code in the question, ideally in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let quots = [
  'quot1',
  'quot2',
  //...
];

$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    $('#quotBox').text(quots[Math.floor(Math.random() * quots.length)]);
});
```

Comment: I think this is close and correct for random click text. I love it

Answer (score 0):

This is for single text change. Not for array.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".txtchange").click(function(){
    $("p").text("New Text!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="txtchange">Change</button>

<p>A Simple Text.</p>
```

Comment: Code :   https://codepen.io/zahour9/pen/qByqgOY?editors=1010